# Motives and topoi

Tags: algebraic-geometry

can someone bring me an "beginner" material to topoi and Grothendieck's motives? I am eager to work with them, but I only find advanced material. Thanks!

Comment: I think this would be better suited to math.stackexchange. That said, if you ask this there you should explain more: what is your background (e.g. are you familiar with cohomology?), and what exactly do you mean by "beginner" in this context? (Topoi and motives are definitely advanced material, so presumably "beginner" is relative.)

Comment: http://www.ams.org/notices/200410/what-is.pdf

http://www.ams.org/notices/200409/what-is-illusie.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try: https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2010/12/an_informal_introduction_to_to.html for topos theory.  The author states that he's "no expert on topos theory. These notes are for people even less expert than me".

You can also find "an introduction to topos theory" on this page: http://www.fuw.edu.pl/~kostecki/.  Supposedly, "This text is designed as an elementary introduction, written in a self-contained way, with no previous knowledge required."

Edit: follow up with this - http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/topos.html because it provides pathways to the advanced material.

Disclaimer: I have accumulated this stuff because "one of these days" I'll get around to looking at it, not because I have any knowledge of the contents.

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks :)